# Sheet name equal to name of input text file

Tags: excel, vba

Updated.

I have the following code:

```
Sub ImportTextFile()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If Val(Application.Version) > 15 Then
If ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn Then ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
End If
Dim Ret
Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet
Set newWorksheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Konvertering"))
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If Ret <> False Then
With newWorksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=newWorksheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "Sample"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    newWorksheet.Name = Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)
End If
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It imports a textfile to a new sheet in Excel. How can I update the code so that the new sheet gets the same name as the textfile that was imported?

Comment: try something like `activesheet.name = ret`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when adding the new worksheet, assign it to an object variable for reference later...

```
Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet
Set newWorksheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Konvertering"))
```

Then, you can refer to the new worksheet for your query and name your new worksheet as follows...

```
If Ret <> False Then
    With newWorksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=newWorksheet.Range("$A$1"))
        'etc
        '
        '
    End With
    newWorksheet.Name = Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried updating the code, but I received an error message stating "You typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart...". The name of the textfile is "ALL RULES IN DSK-V 01042020, and this should also be the name of the new worksheet. I have updated the code in the original post. Could you have a look to see what I have done wrong?

Comment: When the text file is selected, what is the path and filename assigned to `Ret`?

Comment: When executing "Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")". The consol opens, and I have to chose the textfile. So the path is where the textfile is saved. I want this to be flexible, so it does not matter where the textfile is located. The filename will also vary as I want to be able to use different textfiles.

Comment: Yes, I understand that path and filename will differ depending on user selection.  But when you get that error, what path and filename has been assigned to `Ret`?

Comment: C:\Users\AC67899\OneDrive - GHN SERVICES ASA\Desktop\Konvertering\ALL RULES IN DSK-V 01042020

Comment: Is it possible to adjust "newWorksheet.Name = Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)" so it only returns everything after the last "\"?

Comment: `Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)` should return `ALL RULES IN DSK-V 01042020`, as you would expect (although, it should have included the .txt extension).  And, since there doesn't appear to be any invalid characters, it should be fine.

Comment: For testing purposes, temporarily replace `newWorksheet.Name = Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)` with `Debug.Print Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)`.  Now run it again, and see what is printed in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).  What does it print?

Comment: It prints "ALL RULES IN DSK-V 01042020.txt"

Comment: The issues was that with the ".txt" extension it exceeds 31 characters with the textfile I used (the name I posted here was a bit modified). Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

## Double InstrRev

You were just another `InstrRev` away from the solution.

Let's say the path is `C:\Test\Input.txt`.

After applying `InstrRev` with `\` to `Ret` ...

```
x = Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)
```

you got this: `Input.txt`.

Now you just have to apply `InstrRev` with `.` to `x` ...

```
FileName = Mid$(x, 1, InStrRev(x, ".") - 1)
```

to get this: `Input`.

And now you have to get rid off `x` i.e. replace `x` in the second expression with the right side of the first expression to get this:

```
FileName = Mid$(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), 1, _
  InStrRev(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), ".") - 1)
```

Hence the solution:

Replace this ...

```
newWorksheet.Name = Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1)
```

...with

```
newWorksheet.Name = Mid$(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), 1, _
  InStrRev(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), ".") - 1)
```

...and you're done.

### EDIT:

**Links**

[Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

[XlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextFile()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ' The following line is usually written immediately after the previous
    ' two lines.
    On Error GoTo ProgramError
    If Val(Application.Version) > 15 Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn Then ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
    End If
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet             ' For Each Control Variable
    Dim finishSuccess As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String
    Set newWorksheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Konvertering"))
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    ' Define fileName
    fileName = Mid$(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), 1, _
      InStrRev(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), ".") - 1)
    ' Check if fileName exceeds 31 character limit:
    If Len(fileName) > 31 Then GoTo FileNameTooLong
    ' Check if worksheet name exists.
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = fileName Then GoTo WorksheetNameTaken
    Next ws
    ' Import Text File
    If Ret = False Then GoTo SafeExit
    With newWorksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=newWorksheet.Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    newWorksheet.Name = fileName
    ' Stop Excel complaining about losing the code.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ' Assuming you want to save the file as .xlsx (without code).
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ' If you want to save as .xlsm (with code) then use
        ' 'xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled' and remove the lines
        ' containing 'Application.DisplayAlerts ...'.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' If I'm mmissing the point, just outcomment the previous Application
    ' block and uncomment the following line and make changes appropriately.
'    Thisworkbook.SaveAs fileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    finishSuccess = True

SafeExit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If finishSuccess Then
        MsgBox "Finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"
        ' Close workbook without saving changes (False) ensuring that it
        ' always stays the same. Remove 'False' if I'm missing the point.
        ThisWorkbook.Close False
    End If

Exit Sub

WorksheetNameTaken:
    MsgBox "There is already a worksheet named '" & fileName & "'.", _
      vbInformation, "Custom Error Message"
    GoTo SafeExit ' or change appropriately.

FileNameTooLong:
    MsgBox "The file name '" & fileName & "' exceeds the 31 character limit.", _
      vbInformation, "Custom Error Message"
    GoTo SafeExit ' or change appropriately.

ProgramError:
   ' Handle Error (You can do better. A hint: 'vbYesNo'.)
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred. Error '" & Err.Number & "': " _
      & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Custom Error Message"
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo SafeExit ' or change appropriately.

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I use this logic to save the workbook with the same filename as the textfile? I was thinking something like: "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Mid$(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), 1, _
    InStrRev(Mid$(Ret, InStrRev(Ret, "\") + 1), ".") - 1)". But that does not work.